# Replacing every character to upper case using Parallel.ForEach

Tags: regex, c#-4.0, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to replace every character in a string to upper case to learn about parallel programming using Parallel.ForEach. Overall tMatches count is about 136945.

Output file is not in correct order. Replacing character is not placing in correct place. I know parallel.ForEach is not a syncronus process.

Please guide me what i need to do/know to get expected output. My Code is:

```
MatchCollection tMatches = Regex.Matches(_testString, @".", RegexOptions.None);
Parallel.ForEach(tMatches.OfType<Match>(), tMatch =>
{
    _testString = _testString.Remove(tMatch.Index, tMatch.Value.Length);
    _testString = _testString.Insert(tMatch.Index, tMatch.Value.ToUpper());
});

Input:
abcdefgh

Expected Output:
ABCDEFGH
```

Comment: What you do is practically equivalent to `Regex.Replace(_testString, @".", tMatch => tMatch.Value.ToUpper());`. Actually, why not just match only lowercase letters rather than any char other than a newline? Use `@"\p{Ll}"` regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, So in parallel foreach it is not possible?

Comment: What I mean to say is that it is a bad usage example. In this situation, you should not use it.